# Disable azure app insights or telemetry from azure for a uwp application

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I have a UWP app published to store and is being used by customers. I have hooked application insights for the app which were useful sometime back.
I wanted to disable azure telemetry logging. For this, I have updated the build with a few code changes. But there are machines that are still running on our old builds.
So in that case is there a way to disable applications insights from logging any further, so that I don't have to delete the insights completely.
Thanks in advance

Comment: which app insights package are you using? and how do you set up the instrumentation key of app insights, read the key from a config file or use it directly in your code?

Comment: @IvanYang version 2.8.1 and yes it is directly used in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change your code, and the instrumentation key is directly used in the code, I don't think there're any ways to disable the telemetry for a uwp application.

But you can reduce the telemetry data by using [Ingestion sampling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#ingestion-sampling). You can set the Data sampling value to 1%, so most of the data will be filtered out.

One more suggestion is that, next time, you can put the instrumentation key in a config file. In this case, if you don't want to send the data, just replace it with a false key.